# Frontend public files authenticate, is it necessary?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, authentication, sails.js, assets

I have a node server with sails framework.

I have assets folder with all the resources for my angular single page app.
I have 2 server templates, one is login and one is dashboard.

What is the right way to serve the assets folder? Because as I see, the assets folder is public, but I dont want anyone to have access to the dashboard angular templates/images if he is not authenticated. Do I have to authenticate each get request, even if it's for images/css/js, or there is another way I miss?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set Sails policy for asset in your `config/routes.js` like this:

```
module.exports.routes = {
  '/public/path/to/asset': { policy: 'authenticated' }
}
```

Comment: Sounds good. And how do I set the authenticated policy? It's policy method or it's a group? Where do you define it? Is that means that each GET request (image, template, etc..) will have to pass authentication method?